Find SQLite 3 database location in Django project unit tests
I am trying to add more tests for this the Django project. I am struggling to load the SQLite database and debug. A easy way to debug would be to access the SQLite 3 database during testing.  How do I find SQLite 3 database location in Django project unit tests and see if my endpoints are being tested as I expect?
For example, ontest.py has:
from django.test import Client

client = Client()


Is there a way of reverse engineer this class and find the SQLite 3 storage file?

per https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463172/755851 , you can do ./manage.py test --keepdb to persist the test DB... does that solve your problem?

how could I make this work with pytest?

Django uses a memory kept sqlite database for tests by default. So it doesn't create a file. If you need to use a physical one you'll need to alter django's settings/config file. B
As an example you can do this:
    PATH_TO_TEST_DB = SOME_PATH
    TEST_DB_FILE_NAME = 'db_test.sqlite3'

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': PATH_TO_TEST_DB + TEST_DB_FILE_NAME),
        }
    }

If you decide to go with a separate settings file for testing you can  run tests with it using this command
python manage.py test --settings=yourproject.test_settings

how could I make this work with pytest?
